# JPA count NamedQuery

Tags: java, jpa, named-query

how to get count with a namedquery, without getting all the list (it would increase performance I think). This is the named query that doesn't work:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Charakteristika.findAllCount", query = "SELECT COUNT(c) FROM Charakteristika c")
```

Executing this:

```
System.out.println("a");
System.out.println(em.createNamedQuery("Charakteristika.findAllCount", Integer.class).getSingleResult().intValue());
System.out.println("b");
```

Output:

```
a
```

Although this query works:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Charakteristika.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Charakteristika c")
```

Executing this:

```
System.out.println("a");
System.out.println(em.createNamedQuery("Charakteristika.findAll", Charakteristika.class).getResultList().size());
System.out.println("b");
```

Output:

```
a
11111
b
```

Comment: @JBNizet The queries are the same, the execution is different.

Comment: I'm very sorry, problem is still the same, just misspelled second query.

Comment: @JBNizet The second execution specifies the result type to be `Charakteristika.class`; I'm guessing that's throwing things off, returning a count for each of `N` rows.

Comment: @Minutis Generally looks reasonable, so I think more info may be helpful - what's your runtime environment?  JPA engine, version, etc?

Comment: @Minutis: WHICH problem? Tell us what happens.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Change your code likes this;

```
      int count = ((Number)em.createNamedQuery("Charakteristika.findAllCount").getSingleResult()).intValue();
      System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: What is the Number class you're casting the result too? 
Shouldn't it be (int)?

Answer (score 6):

Also you can try it: use TypeQuery interface with Long value. In the next example, "PosicionHistorialDia.findNumberSpeeding" query is a jpa count.

```
    @Override
    public Long findCount(String eventCode) {
         TypedQuery<Long> query = em.createNamedQuery(
            "PosicionHistorialDia.findNumberSpeeding",
            Long.class);
        query.setParameter("event", eventCode);
        return query.getSingleResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
System.out.println("a");
System.out.println(em.createNamedQuery("Charakteristika.findAllCount").getSingleResult());
System.out.println("b");
```

And see if it's output suggests anything to you.

Failing that,

- try `getResultList` instead of `getSingleResult`; otherwise the same.
- try `createQuery("SELECT COUNT(c) FROM Charakteristika c").getSingleResult` & `getResultList`
- Explore differences in declaration of queries; as JB points out, the queries are the same.  So try both names with the different forms above.
- Examine how you're building; is this part of a deployed app?  stand-alone?

Something's gotta give somewhere.

Comment: Nope. No result, no error, just leaves hanging after outputing "a".

Answer (score 0):

another option

```
@NamedQuery(name = "MyTable.countAll", query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable")

long total = entityManager.createNamedQuery("MyTable.countAll", Long.class).getSingleResult();
```